# Laravel 8 Controller not working in live server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp-server

working with laravel 8 project. in my localhost it is working properly. but when I host my project to live server (hostgrator) my controller not working here. I have following web.php route file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('form','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store');

Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@verifyUser');
```

even localhost and live server `welcome` route working properly. but it seems to be my `Route::post('form','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store');` route not working properly on the live server for my contact form in the following

```
<section class="contact" id="contact">
<div class="content">
@include('partials.alerts')
    <h1 class="heading">Contact Us</h1>
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}#contact">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone number*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('telephone'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <textarea cols="2" rows="2" class="full-width" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>
  <button  class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</section>
```

when I click submit button my live sever encounted following error message
`Sorry, this page doesn't exist. Please check the URL or go back a page. 404 Error. Page Not Found.`

and my url displaylike this
`https://tourman.com/form#contact`

but it should be like this if it is work properly like localhost
`http://localhost/#contact`

my controller file is

```
 protected function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate request
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'telephone' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = new User;

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $user->message = $request->input('message');
        
        $user->save();

        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => Str::random(40)
        ]);

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));
return redirect('/#contact')->with('info', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify');
    }
```

what can do for fix my problem here

Comment: Try by removing #contact id in form action and controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Naming Route**

```html
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function () {
       Route::post('/form', 'store')->name('form.store');
       Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'verifyUser')->name('verify.user');
    });
```

**Update Form Action Link**

```html
    <section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="content">
    @include('partials.alerts')
    <h1 class="heading">Contact Us</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('web.form.store')}}">
             @csrf
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone number*" /><br><br>
    <span style="color:red">@error('telephone'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
    <textarea cols="2" rows="2" class="full-width" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>
  <button  class="conbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is admin part of the form action

Comment: actually you are not mentioned your route file name so, you may edit where your routes are.like if your routes in `web.php` so you use `web.form.store` or if you create customize file you may use it .